# Группировка ДТО

Tags: java, песочница

Нужна помощь с группировкой ДТО.
Сейчас, на выходе, я имею такую картину:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По сути, это две записи с пятью параметрами: dayExpenses, defectAge, defectPercentage, fall, weightGain.
Данные берутся из трёх таблиц:

classifiers
[image: classifiers]

attributes

[image: attributes]

attribute_values

[image: attribute_values]

Ответ собирается в отдельном ДТО:

```
public class PigOptionsDto {


private String classifier;
private String fall;
private String defectPercentage;
private String defectAge;
private String weightGain;
private String dayExpenses;
private String attributeVersion;
private LocalDateTime activeFrom;
```

}

Данные наполняются в маппере:

```
public PigOptionsDto classifierAttributesAttValueEntitiesToPigOptionsDto(
        AttributeValuesEntity attributeValues) {
    ClassifierEntity classifier = new ClassifierEntity();
    PigOptionsDto pigOptionsDto = new PigOptionsDto();

    pigOptionsDto.setClassifier(String.valueOf(attributeValues.getClassifiers().getName()));



    pigOptionsDto.setFall(attributeValues.getValue());
    pigOptionsDto.setDefectPercentage(attributeValues.getValue());
    pigOptionsDto.setDefectAge(attributeValues.getValue());
    pigOptionsDto.setWeightGain(attributeValues.getValue());
    pigOptionsDto.setDayExpenses(attributeValues.getValue());
    pigOptionsDto.setActiveFrom(attributeValues.getActiveFrom());

    return pigOptionsDto;
}
```

И вопрос таков, что мне в этом маппере написать, чтобы на выходе получалось не так как на первой картинке, а было бы две записи:

1. classifier: "0kg - 8kg grupa", fall: "2", defectPercentage: "4", defectAge: "6", weightGain: "8", dayExpenses: "10"
2. classifier: "10kg - 50kg grupa", fall: "1", defectPercentage: "3", defectAge: "5", weightGain: "7", dayExpenses: "9"

Как расставить эти параметры по местам?
Если предложенной информации недостаточно, напишите, я дополню.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Маппер в вашем варианте не поможет.

У вас сигнатура метода должна быть примерно

```
public PigOptionsDto classifierAttributesAttValueEntitiesToPigOptionsDto(
        AttributeValuesEntity[] attributeValues)
```

`classifierAttributesAttValueEntitiesToPigOptionsDto` метод должен получить массив значений. А Я так понимаю что вы перебираете массив `AttributeValuesEntity[] attributeValues` поэлементно и на каждый создаёте отдельныю запись.

Правильно будет пишитать нормально запрос и получайте свои записи `PigOptionsDto`
из базы готовыми.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  classifiers.name, 
  fall_values.value as fall, 
  defectPercentage_values.value AS defectPercentage,  
  defectAge_values.value AS defectAge,  
  weightGain_values.value AS weightGain,  
  dayExpenses_values.value AS dayExpenses

FROM classifiers 
LEFT JOIN attributes AS falls
  ON classifiers.id = falls.cls_id
LEFT JOIN attribute_values AS fall_values
  ON classifiers.id = fall_values.cls_id
    AND fall_values.atr_id = 11

LEFT JOIN attributes AS defectPercentages
  ON classifiers.id = defectPercentages.cls_id
LEFT JOIN attribute_values AS defectPercentage_values
  ON classifiers.id = defectPercentage_values.cls_id
    AND defectPercentage_values.atr_id = 12
    

LEFT JOIN attributes AS defectAges
  ON classifiers.id = defectAges.cls_id
LEFT JOIN attribute_values AS defectAge_values
  ON classifiers.id = defectAge_values.cls_id
    AND defectAge_values.atr_id = 13

LEFT JOIN attributes AS weightGains
  ON classifiers.id = weightGains.cls_id
LEFT JOIN attribute_values AS weightGain_values
  ON classifiers.id = weightGain_values.cls_id
    AND weightGain_values.atr_id = 14

LEFT JOIN attributes AS dayExpenses
  ON classifiers.id = dayExpenses.cls_id
LEFT JOIN attribute_values AS dayExpenses_values
  ON classifiers.id = dayExpenses_values.cls_id
    AND dayExpenses_values.atr_id = 15
```